# how do I create a DataFrame mirroring the table below and assign this to data

Tags: python

[how do I create a DataFrame mirroring the table below and assign this to `data`. Then group by the `flavor` column and find the mean price for each flavor; assign this **series** to `price_by_flavor`.

| flavor | scoops | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| chocolate | 1 | 2 |
| vanilla | 1 | 1.5 |
| chocolate | 2 | 3 |
| strawberry | 1 | 2 |
| strawberry | 3 | 4 |
| vanilla | 2 | 2 |
| mint | 1 | 4 |
| mint | 2 | 5 |
| chocolate | 3 | 5 |

Comment: Select and copy your table here to the clipboard (*e.g.* Ctrl + C), then you can do `data = pd.read_clipboard()` and `price_by_flavor = data.groupby('flavor').price.mean()`.

Comment: data =  {
    "flavor":["chocolate", "vanilla", "chocolate", "strawberry", "strawberry", "vanilla", "mint", "mint", "chocolate"], 
    "scoops":[1,1,2,1,3,2,1,2,3],
    "price":[2,1.5,3,2,4,2,4,5,5]
}
price_by_flavor = data.groupby('flavor').price.mean()
price_by_flavor

Comment: Output: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-44-b27e6c3c9251> in <module>
      4     "price":[2,1.5,3,2,4,2,4,5,5]
      5 }
----> 6 price_by_flavor = data.groupby('flavor').price.mean()
      7 price_by_flavor

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'groupby'

Comment: This is what I am getting

Comment: Thank you so much I reevaluated and it worked